# how to fix undefined index in PHP

Tags: php

This is a little question, but why am i getting this error message?

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: filter

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 43
```

It says the problem lays here:

```
$filter2 = $_GET['filter'];
```

I have defined my GET as filter2, i want to use filter2 to compare if it contains the word 'RealScan'

The problem will be fixed if i use isset(), but it will also convert the my GET to a integer, so i cant use that.

```
if($filter2 == 'RealScan')
{
//something here  
}
```

Comment: It means that there is no 'filter' in `$_GET`, so there's no ?filter= in your request.

Comment: If it says undefined index, that means that there's no `filter` parameter set for your `$_GET` variable to get. Where is `filter` coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3):

You need to check to see if it is defined before you use it:

```
$filter2 = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : '';
```

Comment: Too many parentheses will cause an "expected `:`" error.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will accept your answer within 10 min